# ASP.NET MVC: How to delete element from List that is also in List

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, model-binding

I have a list of Brewers, and every brewer has a list of Beers. In my exercice I need to delete a Beer from a specific Brewer.

I see the list of Brewers, I click on the detail, and then I see the names of all Beers this brewer owns.

I understand how to delete a Brewer, but don't understand how to delete beer from this brewer. I definitely need an id of brewer and id of beer.

```
 <td>
    <a asp-controller="Brewer" asp-action="BeerDelete" asp-route-id="@item.BeerId">Delete</a>
</td>
```

here i got a beer id, but how do i manage to get Brewer id again?

Here is the code to delete a Brewer

```
[HttpPost, ActionName("Delete")]
    public IActionResult DeleteConfirmed(int id)
    {
        Brewer brewer = null;
        try
        {
            brewer = _brewerRepository.GetBy(id);
            _brewerRepository.Delete(brewer);
            _brewerRepository.SaveChanges();
            TempData["message"] = $"You successfully deleted brewer { brewer.Name}.";
        }
        catch
        {
            TempData["error"] = $"Sorry, something went wrong, brewer { brewer?.Name} was not deleted…";
        }
        return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
    }
```

May be i need to save somewhere id of brewer?
Or there is a possibility ti get id of brewer, when i'am on his page looking at List of beers?

Delete Brewer
URL: …/Brewer/Delete/4

Delete Beer
URL: .../Brewer/Beer/Delete/{id} ?????
Hopefully i dicribed it good enough..

I tried to do it like this:

```
public IActionResult BeerDelete(int id)
    {
        ViewData[nameof(Beer.Name)] = _brewerRepository.GetBy(id).Beers.FirstOrDefault(e => e.BeerId == id).Name;
        return View();
    }
```

[How I did this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9RI0o.png)

Kind regards, ilya

Comment: It is better that you create a viewmodel instead of ViewData. Then you can create a form in your view and post that model. In the model you can add an brewerId and a beerId
Also it is not clear how your database is build. Are you using entity framework and is it code first? It all depends on the relationships between the two in the database and how that is build.

Comment: Hello, thank you for responce, It is entity framework, code first, Brewer has 0 or many Beers, Beer has exactly one Brewer.

Comment: So is there a brewerId in beer?
That would be advisable. 
You can do it like this: _beerRepository.Where(b => b.BrewerId == brewerId && b.Id == Id).FirstOrDefault();

Comment: I cant use _beerRepository.. i only have  private readonly IBrewerRepository _brewerRepository;
        private readonly ILocationRepository _locationRepository;

        public BrewerController(IBrewerRepository brewerRepository, ILocationRepository locationRepository)
        {
            _brewerRepository = brewerRepository;
            _locationRepository = locationRepository;
        }  on my excercise

Answer (score 0):

This is one of many ways to accomplish deleting a beer from your brewer. I am assuming you have a `ForeignKey` on your beer for the brewer. I could be more precise if I actually knew how the `Brewer` and the `Beer` classes were set up.

View

```
 <td>
    <a asp-controller="Brewer" asp-action="BeerDelete" asp-route-id="@item.BeerId" asp-route-brewerId="@item.BrewerId">Delete</a>
</td>
```

Controller

```
public IActionResult BeerDelete(int id, int brewerId)
    {
        // This would select the beer and pass it into the view as the view's model.
        // Brewer should also be populated for this beer.
        var beer = _brewerRepository.GetBy(brewerId).Beers.FirstOrDefault(e => e.BeerId == id);
        return View(beer);
    }
```

Comment: I am almost close with your help; but a class of Beer Does not know anything about  Brewer, so i dont have property brewerId, A brewer class got list of Beers. I have model map in here with Brewer and Beer https://github.com/pl7771/Beerhall---.net-MVC-with-Moq-testings/tree/master/Beerhall/Models/Domain

Comment: I think @patrick-mcvay helped you out very much, and that it is up to you to finish your exercise, otherwise we are making the exercise instead of you. You need to include the brewerId, and you have it while before you navigate to the beer page, you were on the brewer page right.

Comment: Check into `Shadow Properties`. Since `Beer` doesn't have a foreign key for `Brewer` or a navigation property for `Brewer`, if you used the code first approach, `Entity Framework` would have created a `Shadow Property` for you. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/relationships?tabs=fluent-api%2Cfluent-api-simple-key%2Csimple-key

Comment: Also, I would set up a `DBSet<Beer>` in your `DBContext` class.